# Get elements for the same values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

There is a numpy matrix:

```
bins =array([[2076., -861.84471079],
       [2076., -858.23866597],
       [2076., -861.84471079],
       ...,
       [9757., 1847.33889178],
       [9757., 1830.39082856],
       [9757., -932.14347751]])
```

I want to collect all the elements along the 1 axis for each unique value along the 0 axis:

```
bins = array([[2076., [-861.84471079, -858.2386, -861.84471]],
       [9757., [1847.33889178, 1830.3908, -932.14]]])
```

etc

I did as follows:

```
bins = points_OYZ[points_OYZ[:, 0].argsort()]

vals, idx_start, count = np.unique(bins[:, 0], return_counts=True, return_index=True)

binarize_matrix = np.split(bins, idx_start[1:])

q = []
for i in binarize_matrix:
    min_index = np.argmin(i[:, 1])
    q.append(i[min_index])
```

I would like it to be simpler, but I don't know how, please tell me!

Comment: The output is not a valid numpy array (it's ragged), do you really want that?

Comment: please format your questions correctly. When you are posting an answer, you can get a preview. If what you are seeing isn't formatted well, **then don't post it until you figure out how**.

Comment: As a general rule, grouping like this is not a strong feature of `numpy`.  `pandas` has a grouping tool, and so does python `itertools`.  Things that can make this easier - sorting so unique values are together; make the index column separate and int dtype.  With sorted groups you may be able use slices rather than 'advanced indexing'.  Unless the groups are all the same length then you will need to iterate on the unique values, since the result will a list of arrays that differ in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you would like to do

```
import numpy as np

bins = np.array([[2076., -861.84471079],
             [2076., -858.23866597],
             [2076., -861.84471079],
             [9757., 1847.33889178],
             [9757., 1830.39082856],
             [9757., -932.14347751],
             [9760., -159.14347751]])

vals, idx_start, count = np.unique(bins[:, 0], return_counts=True, return_index=True)

output = [[vals[i], bins[idx_start[i]:idx_start[i]+count[i]][:, 1].tolist()] for i in range(len(vals))]
print(output)
```

output:

```
[[2076.0, [-861.84471079, -858.23866597, -861.84471079]], 
 [9757.0, [1847.33889178, 1830.39082856, -932.14347751]], 
 [9760.0, [-159.14347751]]]
```